# String method Append() : StringBuilder vs StringBuffer

Tags: java, string

With this code:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String s = "Java";
    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(s);
    change(buffer);

       System.out.println("What's strBuf.charAt(5)? " + strBuf.charAt(3));
       System.out.println(buffer);
  }

     private static void change(StringBuilder buffer) {

          buffer.append(" and HTML");
  }
```

When I run the code using StringBuilder I get  error message

```
 The constructor StringBuilder(String) is undefined
    The method charAt(int) is undefined for the type StringBuilder
```

Tried StringBuffer instead and it works.
The content of the StringBuffer object is compiled to "Java and Eclipse.."

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String s = "Java";
    StringBuffer strbuf = new StringBuffer(s);
    change(strbuf);

               System.out.println("The Stringbuffer.charAt(5) is ? " + strbuf.charAt(3));
           System.out.println(strbuf);
 }

       private static void change(StringBuffer strbuf) {

                       strbuf.append(" and Eclipse");
 }
```

}

Comment: @fge You are right, I check the java docs and it indicates that passing a string in the StringBuilder constructor is legal, but it still doesnt work in the version of eclipse i am using .Any suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) *does* have a [constructor accepting a `String` as an argument](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#StringBuilder%28java.lang.String%29), and *does* have [a `.charAt()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#charAt%28int%29) (which it it must implement since it implements `CharSequence`).

Conclusion: this is a mishap from the part of your IDE, which did not import the correct `StringBuilder`. You use another library which has the unfortunate "property" of having implemented a class by the same name -- but not in the same package.

Go see at the top of your file if the import line is:

```
import java.lang.StringBuilder;
```

Comment: it worked , I imported the wrong  StringBuilder class instead of java.lang.Class. Thanks @fge

Comment: "you" imported or your IDE did? ;)

Comment: my IDE suggested it and I proceeded with the suggestion. @fge

Answer (score 3):

You might have imported a wrong StringBuilder class instead of java.lang.StringBuilder which does have a StringBuilder(String) constructor  and charAt(int) method.

Could you check your import. You should have this one

```
import java.lang.StringBuilder;
```

Comment: Thanks @Amin, yes that was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are **not** defining your class name as `StringBuilder`

For Example: 
Even if you import it correctly

```
 import java.lang.StringBuilder;
```

But if you write your class as

```
 public class StringBuilder { //If class name matches below Object Creation
 public static void main(String[] args) {

String s = "Java";
StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(s);  //Object creation
change(buffer);

   System.out.println("What's strBuf.charAt(5)? " + strBuf.charAt(3));
   System.out.println(buffer);
}

 private static void change(StringBuilder buffer) {

      buffer.append(" and HTML"); //you will get this error at append
  //The method append(String) is undefined for the type StringBuilder
} 
}
```

Suggestions

Rename your class name to something else **but not** `StringBuilder`